# dismiss a popup view controller

Tags: ios, swift, popup

I implemented apple pay into my app. When I click on the apple pay button, the standard pay pop up view controller appears. In order to dismiss it, I can press the cancel button but I also want to be able to dismiss the pop-up view by clicking the superview.

```
    func alertClose(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("It is working")
    }


    @IBAction func PayApple(_ sender: Any) {

            let paymentViewController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)
            paymentViewController.delegate = self

            self.present(paymentViewController, animated: true, completion: {
                paymentViewController.view.superview?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                paymentViewController.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertClose(gesture:))))

            })
}
```

But what I have implemented above is not working. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. When I click the superview the apple pay pop up doesn't dismiss.

Comment: I would suggest instead of adding gestureRecognizer in the block inside parentView, you should add it in paymentViewController and add the dismiss method inside the same class as well.

Comment: i used passkit so I actually don't have access to paymentViewController @ParasGorasiya

Comment: So, add gestureRecognizer to paymentViewController.view and not to its superView and also set isUserInteractionEnabled = true for paymentViewController.view

Comment: @ParasGorasiya that isn't working either

Comment: Have the alertClose method been called after tapping on the screen?